# Why is the Zariski topology coarser than standard topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, zariski-topology

I'm trying to learn about the Zariski topology (without prior knowledge of algebraic sets). I'm asked to prove that if $\tau_1$ is the Zariski topology on $\Bbb{C}^2$ and $\tau_2$ is the standard topology on $\Bbb{C}^2$ then $\tau_1$ is coarser than $\tau_2$. So proving $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_2$ wasn't hard - we can think of every open set in $\tau_1$ basis as $U_f=\{x\in\Bbb{C}^2:f(x)\neq 0\}=\Bbb{C}^2\setminus f^{-1}(\{0\})$ which is obviously open in $\tau_2$ since $f$ is continuous. The problem starts when trying to show $\tau_1\subsetneq\tau_2$. What open set in $\tau_2$ is not open in $\tau_2$?

Comment: Any curve that's *not* defined by an algebraic set should get you there.  For example, $\{ (z, w) \in \Bbb C^2  \mid w \neq e^z \}$ should work, although it's not obvious to me how to *prove* this set isn't a union of sets that are open in the Zariski topology.

Comment: @RobertShore Isn't it enough to just show that if $p$ is a nonconstant polynomial then $p(z)-e^z$ is not always zero (which follows by picking any $z$ with large enough modulus)?

Comment: It's easy to prove that $e^z$ isn't a polynomial.  How can you be sure, though, that it's not a union of intersections of polynomial curves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good first step to understand the version with $\mathbb{C}$ in place of $\mathbb{C}^2$. Here we're looking at **single-variable polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$**, and these are relatively simple. In particular, we have a good understanding of $\{u: f(u)=0\}$ for such an $f$:

> It's either finite or all of $\mathbb{C}$.

This means that any closed in the usual sense subset of $\mathbb{C}$ *not* satisfying this same "size condition" cannot be Zariski closed. For example:

> The unit disc $\{x+yi: x^2+y^2\le 1\}$ is closed in the usual sense and infinite but not all of $\mathbb{C}$.

---

OK, now how can we lift this to $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Well, there are various ways to do this, but one I quite like is to consider **sections**. Suppose $f(u,v)$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ in two variables. Fix some $z\in\mathbb{C}$; we then get a *single-variable* polynomial $$g(u)=f(u,z).$$

- What can we say about $\{u: g(u)=0\}$ (thinking about the previous section of this answer?
- How does that give an example of a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{C}^2$ which is closed in the usual topology but not in the Zariski topology?

> HINT: think about $[0,1]$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick proof:

Every Zariski closed subset is quasi-compact (in the Zariski topology). If $\tau_1$ were equal to $\tau_2$, then the same would be true of standard closed sets (in the standard topology), but of course this is not the case, e.g. $\mathbb{C}^2$ itself is closed and not quasi-compact in the standard topology.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're using "quasi-compact" to refer to compactness without the assumption of Hausdorffness, right? (There's a split re: including the Hausdorff condition in the definition of compactness; I learned the non-Hausdorff-assuming definition.)

Comment: Sorry! Yes by "quasi-compact" I meant "every open cover has a finite subcover".